# onChange event not working when build html code by function - REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I have a .js file with a component code that build a page containing:

- a table with filters (in the example below just a combo box)
- a table with data
- a button "close"

  ```
    const My_Component = (props) => {

        //My state declaration, other constants, other functions,  etc...

        function handleChange(event) {
            const VALUE = event.target.value;
            console.log('VALUE=' + JSON.stringify(VALUE)  );            
        }


        const build_CodiceHtml = (HANDLE_onChange__Arg ) => {
                let HTML_CODE= '<select onChange="{' + HANDLE_onChange__Arg + '}" name="MY_NAME" value="MY_VALUE" size="sm" className="text-center"  >';
                HTML_CODE=HTML_CODE + '<option value="1">AAAAA</option>';
                HTML_CODE=HTML_CODE + '<option value="2">BBBBB</option>';
                HTML_CODE=HTML_CODE + '<option value="3">CCCCC</option>';
                HTML_CODE=HTML_CODE + '</select>';

                return  HTML_CODE;
        }




        const getTableFiltri = () => {

            let result=''; 

            result = result + '<table cellpadding="20" style="border:1px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><tbody>';
            result = result + '<tr className="justify-content-md-center"  ><td>';
            result = result +  build_CodiceHtml(handleChange);
            result = result + '</td></tr>';
            result = result + '</tbody></table>';

            return result;
        }




        const getTableWithValue = () => {
            //......
        }





        return (

            <div>
                <Modal show={props.isOpen} size="xl">

                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>
                           <section>MY_TITLE</section> 
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body className="modalBody">

                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: getTableFiltri() }} />

                        { getTableWithValue() }

                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.toggle}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>

                </Modal>
            </div>
        )

    }
  ```

Just consider that I need to build the combobox html by a function (in the real life I have some algorithms in order to build the html code of filters).
When a combobox item is selected it should be called the "handleChange()" function.
This code doesn't work because the "handleChange()" function is not called, nothing happen when I select a combobox item.

Moreover, if I have a look to the page analysis of browser I get:

```
<select onchange="{function handleChange(event) {
    var VALUE = event.target.value;
    console.log('VALUE=' + JSON.stringify(VALUE));
  }}"  name="2" value="1" size="sm" classname="text-center"  >
  <option value="1">AAAAA</option>
  <option value="2">BBBBB</option>
  <option value="3">CCCCC</option>
</select>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the reason you're creating a string and then doing dangerouslySetInnerHTML? Does something prevent you from doing this with JSX elements? You say "(in the real life I have some algorithms in order to build the html code of filters)", but i don't see why those algorithms couldn't produce JSX.

Comment: Are you saying to not use dangerouslySetInnerHTML? But if I don't use dangerouslySetInnerHTML (so I simply put '{ getTableWithValue() }' ), the filter table is not shown: the browser (instead of the table containing the combobox), print on screen the html code of the table containing the combobox.

Comment: `Are you saying to not use dangerouslySetInnerHTML?` Yes, unless you have a very good reason to use it, don't use it. You'll need to change your code to make JSX elements, not a string. Do you need an example of how to create JSX elements in a function?

Comment: Yes, thanks. 
Just to add some details, in the real life I have some 'for' cycles that analyzes data received from somewhere, and build the GUI elements for filters (Combobox, radio button, text area, datapicker, etc...). I was able to buld the html code that build those GUI elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason why `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is needed. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is an escape hatch that's occasionally needed to bypass react and put raw html onto the page, but if you can stick to using standard react JSX elements, that will make your code simpler (not to mention safer). It will also fix your onChange issue, because react will hook up the onChange function for you.

For example:

```
const build_CodiceHtml = (HANDLE_onChange__Arg) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={HANDLE_onChange__Arg}
      name="MY_NAME"
      value="MYVALUE"
      size="sm"
      className="text-center"
    >
      <option value="1">AAAAA</option>
      <option value="2">BBBBB</option>
      <option value="3">CCCCC</option>
    </select>
  );
};

const getTableFiltri = () => {
  return (
    <table
      cellPadding="20"
      style={{
        border: "1px solid black",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr className="justify-content-md-center">
          <td>{build_CodiceHtml(handleChange)}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

// ...
<Modal.Body className="modalBody">
  <div>{getTableFiltri()}</div>
  {getTableWithValue()}
</Modal.Body>;
```

Comment: mmmmm.... please consider for example that I cannot simply put the 3 items AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, but I need to put a "for" cycle with N elements. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to render a list of elements in react? Typically that's done by calling `.map` on an array of data to create an array of elements. Or you can make an array of elements by any other means, such as a for loop. You may want to read the react tutorial: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#rendering-lists

Answer (score 0):

Yeah **Nicholas Tower** is right. If you still want to do it your way, then you need to remove the double quotes to make it work.

```js
const build_CodiceHtml = (HANDLE_onChange__Arg ) => {
  let HTML_CODE= `
  <select onChange="(${HANDLE_onChange__Arg})(event)" name="MY_NAME" value="MY_VALUE" size="sm" className="text-center"  >';
    <option value="1">AAAAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBBBB</option>
    <option value="3">CCCCC</option>
  </select>`

  return  HTML_CODE;
}
```

Comment: without double quote the combobox is not shown....

Comment: Updated the code @Fausto70, check it out this one is working